# What are the specifics of installing CMake 3.3 alongside CMake 2.8?

Tags: c++, c, build, installation, cmake

I already have CMake2.8 installed, but I would like to install CMake3.3. Can I run into problems when installing both versions alongside each other? Also, how could I specify which CMake version I would like to use when installing packages? To be more specific, how would I run CMake3.3 rather than CMake2.8 and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, having multiple versions of CMake is no different than having multiple versions of any other program. Just make sure the one you are executing is the one you want, which means you either always reference it using an absolute path, or you manipulate your `PATH` environment variable so the one you want is before the one you do not want. To avoid problems and conflicts with the installers/package managers, I simply install CMake directly by either building it from source of unpacking a pre-built from an archive. This way, I control its installed location.

As a good practice inside a `CMakeLists.txt`, you should always use the [CMAKE_COMMAND](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/CMAKE_COMMAND.html#cmake-command) variable when invoking CMake subprocesses. Documentation for `CMAKE_COMMAND` says, it is "the full path to the CMake executable."